# How Can You Reinstantiate EnvironmentObjects is SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, firebase

I am working on a SwiftUI project and using Firebase. Part of the app allows users to add business addresses to their account. In Firebase I add a BusinessAddress as a sub collection to the user.

User -> BusinessAddresses

In iOS I am using snapshotlistners and Combine to get the data from Firestore. My issue happens when one user logs out and a new user logs in. The business addresses from the first user continue to show in the view that is designated to show business addresses.

I've confirmed the Firebase code is working properly. What seems to be happening is that the creation of BusinessAddressViewModel maintains the original instance of BusinessAddressRepository from when the first user logs in.

My question is how do I "reset" the instance of businessAddressRepository in my BusinessAddressViewModel when a new user logs in?

**BusinessAddressRepository**

This file gets the data from Firebase. It gets the currently user that is logged in and pulls the business addresses for this user. For each log in, I can see that the proper user and addresses are being updated here.

```
class BusinessAddressRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var snapshotListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    @Published var businessAddresses = [BusinessAddress]()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
        
    func startSnapshotListener() {
        guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }
        
        if snapshotListener == nil {
            self.snapshotListener = db.collection(FirestoreCollection.users).document(currentUserId.uid).collection(FirestoreCollection.businessAddresses).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                } else {
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("No Business Addresses.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    self.businessAddresses = documents.compactMap { businessAddress in
                        do {
                            print("This is a business address *********** \(businessAddress.documentID)")
                            return try businessAddress.data(as: BusinessAddress.self)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BusinessAddressViewModel**

This file uses Combine to monitor the @published property businessAddresses from bankAccountRepository. This seems to be where the problem is. For some reason, this is holding on to the instance that is created when the app starts up.

```
class BusinessAddressViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository

    @Published var businessAddressRowViewModels = [BusinessAddressRowViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository) {
        self.businessAddressRepository = businessAddressRepository
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    func startCombine() {
        businessAddressRepository
            .$businessAddresses
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { businessAddress in
                businessAddress
                    .map { businessAddress in
                        BusinessAddressRowViewModel(businessAddress: businessAddress)
                    }
            }
            .assign(to: \.businessAddressRowViewModels, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

BusinessAddressViewModel is set up and an @EnvironmentObject in main.

**Main**

```
    @StateObject private var businessAddressViewModel = BusinessAddressViewModel(businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository())

var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(businessAddressViewModel)
}
```

I was able to confirm it's hanging on to the instance in the view BusinessAddressView. Here I use a List that looks at each BusinessAddress in BusinessAddressViewModel. I use print statements in the ForEach and an onAppear that show the BusinessAddresses from the first user.

BusinessAddressView

```
struct BusinessAddressView: View {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var businessAddressViewModel: BusinessAddressViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.businessAddressViewModel.businessAddressRowViewModels, id: \.id) { businessAddressRowViewModel in
                let _ = print("View Business Addresses \(businessAddressRowViewModel.businessAddress.id)")
                NavigationLink(destination: BusinessAddressDetailView(businessAddressDetailViewModel: BusinessAddressDetailViewModel(businessAddress: businessAddressRowViewModel.businessAddress, businessAddressRepository: businessAddressViewModel.businessAddressRepository))
                ) {
                    BusinessAddressRowView(businessAddressRowViewModel: businessAddressRowViewModel)
                }
            } // ForEach
        } // List
        .onAppear(perform: {
            for businessAddress in self.businessAddressViewModel.businessAddressRepository.businessAddresses {
                let _ = print("On Appear Business Addresses \(businessAddress.id)")
            }
        }) // CurrentUserUid onAppear
    } // View
}
```

So, how do I reset the instance of BusinessAddressViewModel and get it to look at the current BusinessAddressRepository?

Comment: You can't create a new instance of a `StateObject`. Instead, structure your view models so that there's a wrapper inside (most likely a `@Published` property) that you *can* reset.

Comment: So using the code I provided above how would this look? I do have a published property but it's not picking up the change.

Comment: I added the following to the onAppear in the view with no luck. self.businessAddressViewModel.businessAddressRepository = BusinessAddressRepository()

Comment: Did you call `startCombine` again afterwards?

Comment: By the way, nested `ObservableObject`s don't work with any of the `@Published` features out-of-the box. You can either rig up your own system to call `objectWillChange` to the parent, but it might be more ideal to restructure your models with `struct`s that will work nicely with `@Published`

Comment: Starting Combine again worked!

Comment: Where am I nesting and ObservableObject?

Comment: Possibly `BusinessAddressRowViewModel`, but since you don't include that code here, it's hard to say precisely. Also `businessAddressRepository`, but since it's not `@Published`, it probably doesn't matter. Especially if you said calling `startCombine` already solved your issue.